# MySQL statement level trigger issue

Tags: mysql

What seems to be the problem in the given trigger ?

```
delimiter $$

create trigger t3
before update on new
if new.points < 0
begin
Update new set new.points = 0 where id=new.id;
endif;
end $$
```

Structure of my table "new" is :

```
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id     | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| name   | varchar(30) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| points | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Why don't you tell us?

Comment: Is this a homework question? Because there are many problems.

Comment: `id=new.id` will be true for all rows where `id` is not NULL.

Comment: I cannot because its not working for me !

Comment: I am just learning how triggers work and here I just want to enter a 0 in the 'points' column every time a negative value for 'points' comes in.

Comment: It says error in syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I made a MySQL trigger, but something like this should be close:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER t3 BEFORE UPDATE ON `new`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.points < 0
THEN
    SET NEW.points = 0;
END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Notes:

- You omitted the FOR EACH ROW
- "new" is a keyword, so can cause some ambiguity; and since it is specifically for triggers makes the trigger hard to read. I've delimited the table name with the ` character and capitalized the keyword uses.
- You cannot UPDATE (or really modify in any way) the table a trigger is on; only the values for the row being processed. That is why the UPDATE was changed to just a SET, and no WHERE clause is needed to specify the row(s).
- The BEGIN...END I added is technically (probably) not needed in this case; but would be if the body of the trigger had multiple statements.

[IF syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html)

[TRIGGER creation syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html)

[MySQL KEYWORDS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)